# how to go to another activity in android if a condition is fulfilled?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am a beginner in android programming.

I was making a quiz app in which I increase score if player answers correctly. If player answers wrong, I want to display game over screen with players final score. I used following code to update score and level with each correct answer and start GameOverActivity.java with a wrong answer:

```
boolean isCorrect(int answerGiven) {
    if (answerGiven == correctAnswer) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well done!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        correctTrueOrFalse = true;
    } else {
        correctTrueOrFalse = false;
    }
    return correctTrueOrFalse;
}

void updateScoreAndLevel(int answerGiven) {
    if (isCorrect(answerGiven)) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= currentLevel; i++) {
            currentScore = currentScore + i;
        }
        currentLevel++;
    }
    else {
        Intent k = new Intent (GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class); //#######
        startActivity(k); 
    }
}
```

But whenever I run this app, the scores and level are successfully updated with each correct answer, but as soon as I give a wrong answer, the app crashes and fails to start GameOverActivity.class (code for the game over screen).

My GameOverActivity file seems to be fully correct and I feel problem is in the `######` marked line. Please help me figure out the problem.

**edit**: my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GameActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    </activity>
</application>
```

yes, i see my GameOverActivity file is not registered in manifest. i thought android studio auto registers files in manifest. so how to register it? remember i have intents in both GameActivity and GameOverActivity files so manifest might have to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Could you share your log?

Comment: And the GameOverAcitivty, seems the error is inside

Comment: your logic its ok, need to see the logs

Comment: Did you register the GameOverAcitivty in AndroidManifest ?-)

Comment: add activity tag `<activity android:name="...` for GameOverActivity in the AndroidManifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your manifest file and try again:

```
<activity android:name=".GameOverActivity" />
```

All your activities have to be declared in your manifest file...